# OpenMP to CUDA: Reduction

Tags: for-loop, cuda, openmp, reduction

I'm trying to figure out how I can use OpenMP's `for reduction()` equivalent in CUDA.  I've done some research online, and none of what I've tried worked.  The code:

```
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        float f = ...  //store return from function to f
        out[i] = f;    //store f to out[i]
        sum += f;      //add f to sum and store in sum
    }
```

I know what `for reduction()` does in OpenMP....it makes the last line of the for loop possible.  But how can I use CUDA to express the same thing?

Thanks!

Comment: There are some examples of doing a reduction in CUDA: http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/cuda/prac4/reduction.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Thrust](http://thrust.github.com/), An STL inspired library that comes with CUDA. See the [Quick Start Guide](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) for examples on how to perform reductions.

Comment: I am using C though, not C++.  Can I still use that?

Comment: CUDA C, written in `.cu` files, is much closer to C++ than C. You can't use Thrust directly in a `.c` file, but you can use it in a `.cpp` or `.cu` file and export functions to your C code with `extern "C"`. You can also switch from C to C++ by changing your file extensions and then just do any (usually minimal) tweaking required to get your project to compile with the C++ compiler.